# Does tidal deformation change the volume as well as the shape of a neutron star?

Tags: astrophysics, neutron-stars

It’s said that according to general relativity, perfect vacuum is Ricci flat, which means variation of the gravitational field only deforms an object without compression or expansion. However, neutron stars are degenerate gas instead of pressure-less liquid, which means the volume is dependent on the pressure. If a neutron star is tidally elongated, will it affect the internal pressure due to the change in its mass distribution? Will it cause the neutron star to expand?

Comment: Not an answer, just a clarification: spacetime is Ricci-flat only where it's empty. It's not empty where neutron star is located, so it's not Ricci-flat there. General relativity is nonlinear, so the idea "it's Ricci-flat except for the neutron star's own gravity" isn't really meaningful, except in the weak-field (linearized) approximation. Are you asking about the weak-field approximation?

Comment: Oh. I forgot that gravitational field is nonlinear, which can’t be separated like electromagnetic field.